# How to show/hide particular button inside dynamic divs from another dynamic list/div having ng-repeat using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

[Here is the image, I am not able to toggle "Remove from cart" to "Add to Cart" by clicking REMOVE button in cart division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Vfb.png)

I have a main div which displays products in a list and we can add product to cart (another div) from there. Button on each item changes to remove from cart after that product is added.
Another div shows the Cart which can control quantity on particular item or remove the item. What I want is when an Item from Cart is removed it should get reflected in main product list (button).

**Here is code for main div :**

```
<div ng-repeat=x in bikes.items>                               
   <div class="col-sm-3 bike-price">
      <h3>Rate: &#8377; {{x.rate}}/hr </h3>
      <h5>Total Available : {{x.available}}</h5>
      <button type="button" ng-hide="x.hide_unhide_AddButton"  class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addvalue(x.bike_name,x.rate,x.available,x.location[0]);hideAddButton(x)">Add to Cart</button>
       <a class="btn" ng-show="x.hide_unhide_AddButton" ng-click="showAddButton(x);callCartDelete(x.bike_name)" style="color:red">Remove from Cart</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
$scope.hideAddButton=function(i) {
  i.hide_unhide_AddButton=true;
  console.log("i="+i);
}
$scope.showAddButton=function(i){
  console.log("i="+i);
  i.hide_unhide_AddButton=false;
}
```

*Cart Div*

```
<div class="cart-item" ng-repeat="value in storeArray track by $index">
     <span>
        <button type="button"  ng-click="FunctionToToggleMainDivButton()" class="btn btn-danger remove" >REMOVE</button>
        <h4>{{value.bike}}
        <small>Bikes Left :{{value.available-1}}
        </small></h4>                                          
     </span>
     <div class="add-more">
       <button type="button" ng-click="IncrementUpdateElement(value.bike)" class="btn btn-success plus-minus">+</button>
       {{value.bike_counter}} 
       <button type="button" ng-click="DecrementUpdateElement(value.bike)" class="btn btn-success plus-minus">-</button>
       <div style="float:right;" >&#8377; {{value.cost * Total_hours}}    </div>
      </div>                                  
 </div>
```

Currently main div add to cart and remove from cart button are working properly inside ng-repeat. But I want them to toggle when I call them from Cart Div. Any help is appreciated.

EDITS:
I got the solution,
following is the plunkr, where I hide show buttons inside ng-repeat from another div having ng-repeat.
https://plnkr.co/edit/ReyvGoHMJM3SMbBMce3x?p=info

Comment: can you post a working sample in a code snippet please?

Comment: Sorry i am not able to create a working plunker, but I have added an image related to the question. Thanks